# ActiveRecord not returning all values from a table when I use 'ModelName.all'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Code is self-explanatory for any rails programmer.

**Migration Code:**

```
class CreateBlogPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    create_table :blog_posts do |t|
      t.string "title"
      t.string "subject"
      t.text "content"
      t.integer "likes"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :blog_posts
  end
end
```

**Route:**

```
resources :blogposts
```

**Controller :**

```
class BlogpostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @all = BlogPost.all 
  end
```

**Model :**

```
class BlogPost < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Matching View :**

```
<h1>
 <%= @all %>
</h1>
```

Output (For that view -- /blogposts/index/):

```
#<BlogPost::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f440816f1e0>
```

In the rails console (for BlogPost.all):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):11
NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for #<BlogPost:0x0000000004749380>)
```

The problem here is: There is already data in the blog_posts table which I can view when I run `select * from blog_posts` in MySQL. But in my view, I get the above output, but rather I'm expecting all the records to be returned and be displayed onto the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

**Hint :** I think I'm not following the Rails' Sensible Defaults.

**P.S :** I'm new to the rails world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@all` is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. When you are calling:

```
<%= @all %>
```

in your view, you are printing that object (and `#<BlogPost::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f440816f1e0>` is a correct output).

If you would like to display records, then you have to iterate over `@all` and display them like this:

```
<% @all.each do |blog_post| %>    
  <h1><%= blog_post.title %></h1>
  <p><%= blog_post.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

The latest problem was solved by restarting Rails server

Comment: Works fine in the browser. But when I run BlogPost.all in the Rails Console. I'm getting 'Undefined Method Error'. What's that about?

Comment: Ok, tell me what you are going to achieve since the records are displayed correctly in the browser.

Comment: Nothing I'm going to achieve. I'm learning rails and I have another Model which returns all the records when I run ModelName.all and the above doesn't in the console. That was the post.

Comment: Can you show us your `PostBlog` model? Just add it to the question with the file name you of your model.

Comment: Ok, so your code looks ok. About the latest issue - `BlogPost.all` should work without any issues. What do you get when you call `BlogPost` in the rails console?

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for #<BlogPost:0x0000000004749380>) is the error I get.

Comment: Please call BlogPost (without "all"). What do you get?

Comment: And please note none of the other methods work, like BlogPost.find(:id) or BlogPost.new()

Comment: => #<BlogPost id: nil, title: nil, subject: nil, content: nil, claps: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> is the output for BlogPost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179106/discussion-between-john-mcintyre-jr-and-mrshemek).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inspect](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/inspect) method like this `<%= @all.inspect %>`.
But usually you want to do this while debugging. The right way would be to iterate thought the relation.